# Parse string to int, failing on underscores

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, int

I just discovered that `int('1_34')` will not throw an error because of [PEP 515](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0515/). But I would like it to throw an error. Is there some stricter way of parsing strings to `int`s (and `float`s too) that would avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the string contains an underscore and raise an exception if it does.

Here's an example:

```
s = "1_34"
if "_" in s:
    raise ValueError("string contains an underscore")
else:
    x = int(s)
```

For `s = "1_34"` you'll get:

```
ValueError: string contains an underscore
```

For `s = "134"` you'll have `x = 134`.

Comment: Thanks! Manual way is fairly straightforward. Nothing built in available?

Comment: @gruszczy unfortunately, I don't think so. The only arguments `int` takes are the thing to convert to an int and the base to use. Wrapping this in a function would probably be the closest thing

Answer (score 0):

```
def number(n):
    if n.isdigit():
        return int(n)
    elif n.count(".") == 1 and n.replace(".", "").isdigit():
        return float(n)
    else:
        raise ValueError("Not a number!")




print(number("345"))
print(number("34.5"))
print(number("1_34"))
```

Imo that's the cleanest approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dirty your hands, you can inherit the `builtin` with your own:

```
class Int(int):
    def __init__(self, value):
        if '_' in value:
            raise ValueError("PEP 515 revoked - underscores not allowed")
        else:
            super().__init__()
```

And then might even shadow the builtin `int` if you really have no use for PEP 515:

```
int = Int
# you can always back up the builtin first...
# _int = int
```

Some might not approve of this answer...